# How to sign JWT with a RSA SHA-256 hash

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, postman, office365api, rsa-sha256

I'm trying to get an access token to use office365 api through client credentials. I'm using this guide: [Office 365 Rest API - Daemon week authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351558/office-365-rest-api-daemon-week-authentication)

I'm sending my request using postman (see below)
[Postman Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWlAf.png)

However postman gives me this error when I send the request "AADSTS70002: Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Client assertion contains an invalid signature"

So I'm fairly certain I'm not signing the JWT correctly which is used for the client_assertion parameter in my request. Referring to this stack overflow question [Could not retrieve app only tokens for office 365](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28832017/could-not-retrieve-app-only-tokens-for-office-365) I found that I need to sign it using a RSA SHA-256 hash. However I still couldn't get my JWT to work with any of the resources I found online on how to do this, it still would come back with the same error. Is there an online generator I can use to sign my JWT using a RSA SHA-256 hash? Or any code examples that specifically do this way of singing in C#? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to set up the certificates on Azure AD manifest, see blog [Building Daemon or Service Apps with Office 365 Mail, Calendar, and Contacts APIs (OAuth2 client credential flow)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/)

About how to sign a token, here is the C# sample for your reference,

```
    var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(@"{FILE PATH}\office_365_app.pfx", "PASS_WORD");

    X509SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new X509SigningCredentials(x509Certificate2, SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature, SecurityAlgorithms.Sha256Digest);

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var originalIssuer = "{YOUR CLIENT ID}";

    var issuer = originalIssuer;

    DateTime utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;

    DateTime expired = utcNow + TimeSpan.FromHours(1);

    var claims = new List<Claim> {
        new Claim("aud", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{YOUR_TENENT_ID}/oauth2/token", ClaimValueTypes.String, issuer, originalIssuer),
        new Claim("exp", "1460534173", ClaimValueTypes.DateTime, issuer, originalIssuer), 
        new Claim("jti", "{SOME GUID YOU ASSIGN}", ClaimValueTypes.String, issuer, originalIssuer),
        new Claim("nbf", "1460533573", ClaimValueTypes.String, issuer, originalIssuer),
        new Claim("sub", "{YOUR CLIENT ID}", ClaimValueTypes.String, issuer, originalIssuer)
    };

    ClaimsIdentity subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims: claims);

    JwtSecurityToken jwtToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(
        issuer: issuer,
        signingCredentials: signingCredentials,
        subject: subject) as JwtSecurityToken;

    jwtToken.Header.Remove("typ");

    var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(jwtToken);
```

You can also find the project on GitHub

https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/blob/master/samples/Office365DevQuickStart/JWT-Token

Answer (score 1):

You can also sign your JWT token using JJWT apis given at https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt

The Sample code could look like:

```
                   Map<String, Object> claims = new HashMap<>();
                   claims.put("user", "some user");
                   Calendar expires = Calendar.getInstance();
                   expires.roll(Calendar.HOUR, 1000);
                    Jwts.builder()
                        .setClaims(claims)
                        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                        .setExpiration(expires.getTime())
                        .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, key)
                        .compact();
```

You can also verify your token on [JWT.io](https://jwt.io/)