# Access multiple Office 365 Outlook calendars within organization in UWP using OAuth2.0?

Tags: c#, outlook, uwp, office365api, office365-restapi

My organization currently uses Office365, and I am creating a Universal Windows Platform app that essentially needs to access the calendars of multiple accounts within the organization.  I am currently using the Office365 Rest API, and already can successfully query a single account's calendar data, after getting an OAuth2.0 access token for a particular user.

After searching through multiple resources and existing Stackoverflow questions, I have tried the following with no luck to get multiple user account calendars without having to sign in to each account individually:

- Performing a GET request with the graph API from Microsoft Graph API
- Performing a GET request using navigation paths to users calendars using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29519134/office365-api-accessing-another-users-rooms-calendars) and other variations. (Returns 403 access denied error)

I also found a possible solution by using EWS Managed API, but I was unsure of its compatibility with UWP and our current Office 365 setup.

Lastly, I looked into [building daemon or service apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2015/01/21/building-daemon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow/), but this method seemed really unnecessary and possibly impossible with the current configuration of Azure.  It requires asymmetric key crypt. set up within the system, and re-configuring the app as a whole within Azure.

Any help is appreciated.

[**EDIT**]: FYI all of the calendars have been made public, and can be viewed in the web client of Outlook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found to what I think is the only solution with today's version of UWP and the Office365 REST Api.

First I started up a different application that was compatible with the [EWS Managed API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633710(v=exchg.80).aspx) and made a query to the Microsoft Exchange server that my organization is using.  I tracked this request using Fiddler, the http debugger, to view the actual request and response.  This way, I could find the exact endpoint of my exchange server.

Then, I navigated to the exchange service's URL in my browser, and saved the service's WSDL file, and imported it as a [service reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx) to my UWP solution.

Finally, I set up a Httpclient, and generated a request to match all of the properties of the request made from the successful EWS Managed API call that I tracked in Fiddler.