# Using Office 365 API with only one account

Tags: azure, office365

I am trying to use the Office 365 API to write events to the calendars of anyone at our organization. This should **not** involve the users logging in to Office 365 at any point. The events to add are written out at various points during the day (when the user who would own the event may not even be at a computer), so the per-user token approach doesn't even make sense.

It appears that Microsoft provides an alternative that uses a service account. This account can be used to write to **any** user's calendar (or sending email as any user, etc.). However, I can't find any documentation on doing this. Could anyone provide a link to it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a blog post on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx

Also, if you aren't using Microsoft's client library for this (for example, if you use linux), you'll need to see this too: [Office 365 Rest API - Daemon week authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351558/office-365-rest-api-daemon-week-authentication)